# Microsoft Access formatting: Need format to display either Date or "0". 0 keeps displaying as 12:00:00AM, how to fix?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I need to make it so that the one field either displays the Date or the value of 0. They're two separate formats, and so I can't get Access to mix the two up. Logic functions keep displaying errors for me.

Comment: Hi welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is fairly vague as to what you are attempting to do or what the issue is. I highly recommend reading through these as pages:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer they are both fantastic resources to use when asking or answering questions and will help you get the best answers quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do conditional formatting like so as a "custom" format:

```
[=0] 0; [>0] mm/dd/yyyy;
```

`[=0]` checks if the value is zero, if so, the cell is set to 0.  If it is greater than 0, use `mm/dd/yyyy` or whatever date format you like.

Comment: Sorry for being so ignorant here, but how exactly do I type this in to the expression builder? It keeps giving me syntax error messages

Answer (score 0):

You can use Format. Rename your textbox to be different from the date field name and this as ControlSource:

```
=Format([YourDateField],IIf([YourDateField]=0,"0","yyyy-mm-dd"))
```